# According to Trinitarian theology of Calvinism, was the Word (2nd person of the Trinity) missing from heaven when He (the Word) incarnated on Earth?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, reformed-theology, persons-of-the-trinity, incarnation

What I mean with "missing from heaven" is something like this : 
*A. Only the first and the third persons of the Trinity were in heaven because the second person was on Earth.*

Example:
Q : Where is the second person of the Trinity from 1 AD to 33 AD ?
A : On Earth in the flesh.
Therefore there is no second person of the Trinity in heaven.

---

Not "missing from heaven" is then something like this: 
*B. The first, second and third persons of the Trinity are still in heaven although the second person is at the same time on Earth.*

Example:
Q : Where is the second person of the Trinity from 1 AD to 33 AD ?
A : On Earth in the flesh and in heaven just in spirit.

---

So, according to Trinitarian theology of Calvinism, was the Word (2nd person of the Trinity) missing from heaven when He (the Word) incarnated on Earth ([John 1:14](http://biblehub.com/john/1-14.htm)) or was He in heaven at the same time as He was on Earth?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be a valid question, but as currently worded it is rather unclear and confusing.

Comment: The Word of God cannot be but omnipresent; He cannot be but God at all times. Isn't it safer to say the omnipresent Word was the divine Person of whom Jesus Christ was the incarnation?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden, I think bradimus got what I mean as he answered B ?

Comment: @SolaGratia, do you mean the there is no the Second Person of the Trinity in heaven but on earth when He was incarnated ? Do you mean the answer is A according to Reformed, SolaGratia ?

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of Reformed vs. Catholic or anything else, since I'm not sure it's disputed that the eternal Word is at all times, by nature, omnipresent and therefore obviously in heaven, too. To say a spirit is in a place, and not only analagously or to our senses is to ascribe statiality to a spirit, namely the Word of God. For example, the Word created all things and holds all things together by His own power. He cannot but be everywhere. 'how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.'

Comment: @karma If bradimus answered your question you can click on the check mark next to his answer to select it as the answer you chose. Or if you are not satisfied can wait for more answers to pick and choose.

Comment: @freethinker36, I will wait for some times if maybe there is another answer to my question. If after waiting there's no answer anymore - I will choose bradimus answer as acceptable. Thank you for the suggestion, freethinker36.

Comment: If you like, i can add the Lutheran position of _Logos non extra carnem_ as well.

Comment: @bradimus, I've edited my question. I hope now is very specific now :).

Comment: @curiousdannii, Geremia, Lee Woofenden, KorvinStarmast, Dan , what I want to know is simple : when the Second Person of the Trinity is being breastfeed by the mother on earth, is there the Second Person of the Trinity in heaven or not ?

Comment: But I never thought that although some denomination hold the same thing (which is Trinity) - but it seems the answer to my question will be different from any each of denomination which exist now. :).

Comment: I think the edits make it clear. This is not so much a question about the Trinity as about Hypostatic Union. I'd have to do some reading, but I don't know if this was a major point of controversy until the Calvinist-Lutheran debates. Even then, it seems to have been mostly driven by where Christ's human nature was/is and what that implied for the Eucharist. Many good questions in there.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, the *extra calvinisticum* as it was derisively called by the Lutheran Reformers. The Reformed position is that although the Word is fully united to the human nature it could not completely contained by it.

The [Belgic Confession](https://www.ccel.org/creeds/BelgicConfession.html#Article%2018) discusses the two natures:

> We believe that by being thus conceived the person of the Son has been inseparably united and joined together with human nature, in such a way that there are not two Sons of God, nor two persons, but two natures united in a single person, with each nature retaining its own distinct properties. **Thus his divine nature has always remained uncreated, without beginning of days or end of life, filling heaven and earth.** His human nature has not lost its properties but continues to have those of a creature-- it has a beginning of days; it is of a finite nature and retains all that belongs to a real body. And even though he, by his resurrection, gave it immortality, that nonetheless did not change the reality of his human nature; for our salvation and resurrection depend also on the reality of his body.

The Divine nature was always filling heaven and earth. Note that this continues today with the locations reversed.

From the [Heidelberg Catechism](https://www.ccel.org/creeds/heidelberg-cat.html):

> Question 47 :Is not Christ then with us even to the end of the world, as he has promised?
>
> Answer: Christ is very man and very God; with respect to his human nature, he is no more on earth; but with respect to his Godhead, majesty, grace and spirit, he is at no time absent from us.
>
> Question 48: But if his human nature is not present, wherever his Godhead is, are not then these two natures in Christ separated from one another?
>
> Answer: Not as all, for since the Godhead is illimitable and omnipresent, it must necessarily follow that the same is beyond the limits of the human nature he assumed, and yet is nevertheless in this human nature, and remains personally united to it.

So, the Godhead is 'beyond the limits of the human nature' and 'omnipresent'. Today, while Christ's body has ascended to Heaven, his Godhead is still with us -- beyond the limitations of the body. Likewise, while he sojourned on earth, His Godhead was still (also) with the Father and Spirit.

Answer B

It should be noted that this idea is often identified with Calvin, it can be found in the Fathers as well.